# The name "FormulaIngredents" does not exist in the current context?

Tags: asp.net, json, model-view-controller

I am trying to return sting "FormulaIngredents" using JSON request but getting an error The name "FormulaIngredents" does not exist in the current context? How I can solve this issue?

```
public JsonResult selectedTags(string[] selectedTags)
        {

            foreach (var item in selectedTags)   
            {
                string FormulaIngredents = string.Join(",", item);
            }
            return Json(FormulaIngredents, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public JsonResult selectedTags(string[] selectedTags)
    {
        string FormulaIngredents = string.Empty;
        foreach (var item in selectedTags)   
        {
            FormulaIngredents = string.Join(",", item);
        }
        return Json(FormulaIngredents, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```